# How should I compute the Monte Carlo mean square error in R?

Tags: r, simulation, mean

I try to get the Monte Carlo mean square error of the maximal likelihood estimators in R. I can write the calculation for the MLE that is repeated once, but I need to repeat the Monte Carlo calculation many times. How should I write this in R?

Firstly, we have sample size `n=20` and the repetition `N=30`. The idea is that for the first repetition, we sample `n=20` data from the Gumbel distribution with location 0 and scale 1 (true value `mu=0` and `sigma=1`).

```
library(VGAM)
set.seed(101)
x <- rgumbel(20, loc = 0, scale = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the philosophy of Monte Carlo and your attempt, I think you can try `replicate` + `rowMeans` (I think this combo applies to your update with `fevd` as well but I kept using `optim` here)

```
N <- 30

est <- replicate(N, {
  x <- rgumbel(20, loc = 0, scale = 1)
  m <- length(x)
  fit <- optim(
    par = c(1, 1),
    fn = ll_fn, z = x, m = m,
    hessian = TRUE, control = list(fnscale = -1)
  )
  fit$par
})

mse <- rowMeans((est - c(0, 1))^2)
```

and you will obtain

```
> est
           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]         [,6]
[1,] 0.03994695 0.0411953 0.04289633 0.4483689 -0.1757629 -0.002960991
[2,] 0.86737551 1.0367012 0.78748509 1.3409259  1.1527607  1.277664938
            [,7]       [,8]      [,9]      [,10]       [,11]       [,12]
[1,] -0.05394607 0.07246731 0.9500388 -0.2932722 -0.03107634 -0.01794733
[2,]  0.67182217 0.99549765 1.4256878  0.9107769  1.03009996  0.59352028
          [,13]     [,14]      [,15]      [,16]      [,17]      [,18]     [,19]
[1,] -0.2268109 0.1411913 -0.1689498 -0.1452246 -0.3621658 0.02991549 0.1332464
[2,]  0.7631312 1.0881250  0.9639512  0.9912077  0.8454992 1.08480054 1.0938930
          [,20]     [,21]     [,22]     [,23]     [,24]      [,25]       [,26]
[1,] 0.03264025 0.2279907 0.5108963 0.2505532 0.1572398 -0.4195196 -0.09234722
[2,] 0.89162837 1.0663945 1.0713617 0.8400802 0.6026962  0.8300022  0.61653388
          [,27]     [,28]       [,29]     [,30]
[1,] -0.1322638 0.0582058 -0.03012397 0.1494059
[2,]  1.0835487 0.8667572  1.05939105 0.8632393

> mse
[1] 0.07120414 0.04254979
```

In `est`, the first row is for `mu`, and the second row is for `sigma`, and `mse` consists of `mu` (1st val) and `sigma` (2nd val)

Comment: @oliver I think you should use `set.seed(101)` outside `for` loop.